# change the cell color of a StringGrid when entering data in the cell. Delphi

Tags: delphi

Good evening, I would like to know how to change the color of a cell when writing data in it

I have this...

```
procedure TFrmReportes.SGDrawCell(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer;
  Rect: TRect; State: TGridDrawState);
begin

   if (gdSelected in State) then
      begin
      SG.Canvas.Brush.Color := rgb(255,119,119);
      SG.Canvas.FillRect(SG.CellRect(ACol, ARow));
      SG.Canvas.TextOut(Rect.Left+2,Rect.Top+2, SG.Cells[ACol, ARow]);

      end;
end;
```

but when entering data in the cell, it turns white

Thanks Again!!!

Answer (score 4):

`TStringGrid` displays a [`TInplaceEdit`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Grids.TInplaceEdit) on top of the cell currently being edited. That `TInplaceEdit` covers the entire cell. That is why you don't see your custom drawing. You would need to change the `TInplaceEdit`'s `Color` property instead. You can access the `TInplaceEdit` via the [`TStringGrid.InplaceEditor`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Grids.TCustomGrid.InplaceEditor) property.

I would suggest deriving a new component from `TStringGrid` and override its virtual [`CreateEditor()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Grids.TCustomGrid.CreateEditor) method. If there is only 1 grid in your Form, a simple interposer would suffice, eg:

```pascal
type
  TStringGrid = class(Vcl.Grids.TStringGrid)
  protected
    function CreateEditor: TInplaceEdit; override;
  end;

  TFrmReportes = class(TForm)
    SG: TStringGrid;
    ...
  end;

...

type
  TInplaceEditAccess = class(TInplaceEdit)
  end;

function TStringGrid.CreateEditor: TInplaceEdit;
begin
  Result := inherited CreateEditor;
  TInplaceEditAccess(Result).Color := RGB(255, 119, 119);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the following code that served me thanks to your suggestion in the previous example
with the InplaceEditor property

```
type
    THackGrid = class(TCustomGrid)
    public
      property InPlaceEditor;
      property EditorMode;
    end;

TFrmReportes = class(TForm)
    SG: TStringGrid;
    ...
  end;

...

procedure TFrmReportes.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   THackGrid(SG).InPlaceEditor.Brush.Color := RGB(255, 119, 119);
end;
```

thank you very much